# Rails admin cascading dropdown how to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

As you see in image below after selection of product attribute i want to filter the options based on the selected attribute_id
this is in rails_admin
[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to say there's no builtin way to do this. 
You'll have to clone the existing belongs to field.
Check out the field implementation 
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/lib/rails_admin/config/fields/types/belongs_to_association.rb
And its view
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/blob/master/app/views/rails_admin/main/_form_filtering_select.html.haml

You'll find more details on how to create your own custom field here
https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin/wiki/Custom-field